# Where is format.exe in windows vista?

Tags: windows-vista, format

As the question states, where is the executable located? I've tried searching everywhere and can't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine has it located here (MS Vista Business 32 bit):

C:\Windows\System32\format.com

You may of course have to enable viewing of Hidden/System files and disable the Hide Protected Operating System files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's called `format.com` and it's in `C:\Windows\System32`